# VERY SIMPLE list interpolation in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I know about numpy.interp and scipy.interpolate.interp1d, but I can't seem to figure out how to just do a very simple linear interpolation between two lists based on some kind of `[0, 1]` range. For example if I have lists

```
x = [2., 3., 4.]
y = [3., 4., 8.5]
```

I want a function that will accept 0.5 as an argument and give me

```
[2.5, 3.5, 6.25]
```

or will accept 0.1 as an argument and give me 5.25, etc.

```
[2.1, 3.1, 6.25]
```

Why am I blanking on this? The answer must be quite easy...

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the third value in the second example be `4.45`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over multiple lists simultaneously.

Put this in an explicit for loop or in a list comprehension (or pass it to [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map), as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571034/3005167)). I think the code is quite self-explanatory:

```
def with_explicit_loop(x_list, y_list, alpha=0.5):
    z_list = []
    for a, b in zip(x_list, y_list):
        z_list.append(a * (1 - alpha) + b * alpha)
    return z_list

def with_list_comprehension(x_list, y_list, alpha=0.5):
    return [a * (1 - alpha) + b * alpha for a, b in zip(x_list, y_list)]
```

Both functions are equivalent, but I think the first is slightly easier to read and the second is slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```
In [10]: lin = lambda x, y, mult: map(lambda (a,b): a*(1-mult) + b*(mult), zip(x, y))

In [11]: lin(x, y, .1)
Out[11]: [2.1, 3.1, 4.45]

In [12]: lin(x, y, .5)
Out[12]: [2.5, 3.5, 6.25]
```

Comment: A one-liner is far less valuable than an expanded answer that spells out the steps required.

Comment: I very much appreciate the great solution, but indeed, I don't understand exactly how this works! What's "lambda," and how does the "mult" variable work?

Cheers

Comment: `lambda` is for defining a (usually anonymous) function, though I'm assigning it to `lin` here. It's the same as if I did `def lin(x, y, mult)`. `zip` pairs up elements from the two lists, and `map` applies the multiplication and addition to each pair.

Comment: the zip is not really necessary here

Comment: Daniel S, the `zip` is to allow us to operate on the paired elements. There are certainly other ways to go about that (e.g., iterating over indexes), but `zip` is by far the most readable and idiomatic.